# SSIS package using SQL Configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to convert my SSIS package from using a dtsConfig file to use SQL Server configuration (by accessing the [SSIS Configurations] table).  I'm getting strange errors running from an Agent job when it worked just fine using the dtsConfig file with the same parameters selected for the config.  I'm not sure about whether I need to select the data sources.  I don't need to include data source information with dtsConfig to get it to run.  Including connection string information is adequate for dtsConfig.  I'm not sure how it knows how to connect to SQL to look for the config info.

Is there a trick to this?  Do I need to tell Agent to use SQL configuration?  I removed the dtsConfig file, but I don't see anywhere to tell it to use SQL config.

Comment: In the Job Steps Properties dialog, open the "Configurations" tab and put in the location of your config file.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use 'SQL Server' configuration with the [SSIS Configurations] table, not the XML dtsConfig file (which works fine). The job doesn't appear to understand how to connect to SQL Server so that it can access the [SSIS Configurations] table. I don't know how to tell it.